# Node js aggregation and findone concept

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to find the history of **person1** deals..so in my getHistory module i have filtered all the deals in that **person1's** dealSchema , in **acceptreject** function i have used aggregation concept to filter the deals which have **person1's** _d in the accepted field. But the callback function  acceptreject does not fetch the result it always results in []..anyone please findout the mistake i have done in this code..Thanks in advance

```
var acceptreject = function (userId, callback){//callback function for finding accepted deal
console.log("Aggregate:" +userId);
if(userId == null && userId == 'undefined'){
 console.log("error fetching id");
  res.send(new Response.respondWithData('failed','Invalid userId'));
  return next();
  }
 User.aggregate([
 {
   $unwind: "$deals"
 },
 {
  "$match":
   {
  "deals.accepted": userId
  //"deals.rejected": id
   }
   },
  {
  $project:{
    "shopName":"$deals.shopName",
    "deal":"$deals.deal",
    "price":"$deals.price",
    "name":"$name"
  }
}
],function (err, user){
  console.log(user);
  if (err){
  callback (err);
   }
   console.log("Your accepted deal:"+ user);
 //  res.send(200,user);
    callback(null, user);
  })
 }
exports.getHistory = function (req, res, next) {
  var incomingUser = req.user;
  var id = incomingUser._id;
  User.findById(id,function (err, user){
   console.log(user);
    if (err) {
    return next(new Response.respondWithData('failed','Cant find theuser'));
    }
   var dealObj = _.filter(user.deals);
   acceptreject({
    userId : id
    },function(err, users){
     if(err){
     res.send(new restify.InternaError(err.message));
     return next();
     }
    else{
     console.log("final");
     var final = {
       accepteddeal: users,//it returns [] in result but person1 accepted the deal
       mydeal: dealObj
     }
     next(res.send(200, final));
   }
  });
  });
  }
```

And my schema is

```
var dealSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 shopName: {type: String,required: true},
deal: {type: String,required: true},
price:{type: Number,required: true},
start:{type: Date,default: Date.now}, 
end:{type: Date},
expiry:{type: Date},
comments:{type: String},
accepted: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'user'},//person1 _id
rejected: {type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}
});
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: { type: String,required: true},
 phone: { type: Number, required: true,unique: true},
 email:{type: String},
 password: {type: String},
deals:[dealSchema]
 }, {collection: 'user'});
mongoose.model('Deal', dealSchema);
mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a mistake in callback function where the userId parameter of that function does not pass the id

```
var accept= function (userId, callback){
console.log("Aggregate:" +userId);
if(userId == null && userId == 'undefined'){
res.send(new Response.respondWithData('failed','Invalid userId'));
return next();
}
var id = new Object(userId);
console.log(id);

 User.aggregate([
 {
   $unwind: "$deals"
 },
 {
  "$match": {
    "deals.accepted" : id
  }
  },
 {
  $project:{
    "shopName":"$deals.shopName",
    "deal":"$deals.deal",
    "price":"$deals.price",
    "name":"$name"
  }
  }
 ],function (err, user){
 console.log(user);
 if (err){
  callback(err);
 }
 console.log("Your accepted deal:"+ user);
  //res.send(200,user);
   callback(null, user);
 })
 }
```